# Convert datetime object in json into java DateTime object

Tags: java, datetime

I have string value `{"date":{"year":2021,"month":11,"day":11},"time":{"hour":10,"minute":30,"second":45,"nano":222000000}}`

Is there any available function or efficient way to convert this JSON String into Java DateTime object rather than read fields one by one and build my object?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

public class App {

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DateC1 {
    private Integer year;
    private Integer month;
    private Integer day;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Root {
    private DateC1 date;
    private Time time;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Time {
    private Integer hour;
    private Integer minute;
    private Integer second;
    private Integer nano;

}

private static final String DATE_JSON_STRING =
        "{\"date\":{\"year\":2021,\"month\":11,\"day\":11},\"time\":{\"hour\":10,\"minute\":30,\"second\":45,\"nano\":222000000}}";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    DateC1 dateC1 = gson.fromJson(DATE_JSON_STRING, DateC1.class);
    System.out.println(dateC1.toString());

}
```

}

Comment: Use lombok & gson dependency

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Java model object, using ObjectMapper convert json string to java object.

Comment: to improve the answer, please provide a code example